# Create TFLite file with InceptionV3 and Food101

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-recognition

Im trying to create a TFLITE model to use on Android.
Im using InceptionV3Model with Food101 dataset.
Im new to this all ML world.
I found this code from TensorFlow that Im trying to use :

https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

I can't figure out where to add and what to add to convert the model into TFLite.

Please explain me about checkpoints and frozen graphs, and help to create TFLite model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could first export the model to saved_model by settting `--saved_model_dir` 
and then using `TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter#from_saved_model